# Find bit sequences that do not include specific sequence

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find all non-overlap bit sequences satisfied the following constraints:

- starts with `0`
- ends with `110` or `111`
- does not contain `000`

Here is my non-regex code in python:

```py
def f(s):
    ans = []
    match = ''
    for i in s:
        if match=='':
            if i=='0':
                match = '0'
            continue
        match += i
        if match.endswith('110') or match.endswith('111'):
            ans.append(match)
            match = ''
        if match.endswith('000'):
            match = '00'
    return ans
```

My current regex pattern is `(0(^(?!000))*(?:110|111))`. It doesn't accept any bit between starting `0` and ending bits. For example, `010110` will return `0110` instead of expected `010110`. Adding `\d*?`, however, accepts sequences including `000`.

```py
>>> s = 1000001110001011001101011000010101100001001100001111
>>> f(s) # expected
['00111', '0010110', '0110', '0110', '001010110', '00100110', '00111']
>>> pat1 = re.compile('(0(^(?!000))*(?:110|111))')
>>> pat2 = re.compile('(0\d*?(^(?!000)\d+)*\d*?(?:110|111))')
>>> re.findall(pat1, s)
[('0111', ''), ('0110', ''), ('0110', ''), ('0110', ''), ('0110', ''), ('0110', ''), ('0111', '')]
>>> re.findall(pat2, s)
[('00000111', ''), ('00010110', ''), ('0110', ''), ('0110', ''), ('0001010110', ''), ('000100110', ''), ('000111', '')]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Like this? `0(?!00)(?:(?!000)[10])*?11[01]` https://regex101.com/r/VZB9OM/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start the pattern by matching a zero, and assert not 2 zeroes directly to the right.

Then match until the first occurrence of either 111 or 110 with no occurrence of 000 in between.

```
0(?!00)(?:(?!000)[10])*?11[01]
```

- `0` Match a single 0
- `(?!00)` Assert not `00` directly to the right
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?!000)[10]` Assert not `000` directly to the right and match either `0` or `1`
- `)*?` Optionally repeat the non capture group, non greedy
- `11[01]` Match either 110 or 111

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VZB9OM/1)

Another shorter variation could be:

```
00?(?:1+0{0,2})*?11[01]
```

- `00?` Match 1 or 2 zeroes
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `1+0{0,2}` Match 1+ times a `1` followed by 0, 1 or 2 times a zero
- `)*?` Optionally repeat the non capture group, non greedy
- `11[01]` Match either 110 or 111

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UvtJVB/1)

Comment: Use `(?=0)` instead of `0(?!00)` to be slightly more concise and less repeating the logic of `(?!000)`.

Comment: @blhsing Hi there, I think that will give different matches as there should not be 000 in the match https://regex101.com/r/DrkNk7/1

Comment: Please note that the suggested `(?=0)` replaces your leading `0` as well. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/px8hgc/1

Comment: @blhsing Ah I see what you mean, it would also work indeed :-)